# Regex Invalid escape in HTML pattern Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, regex, google-chrome, escaping

I just wrote a regex to validate Dutch local phone numbers and international phone numbers using regexr. It validates perfectly, however, once moving it to a HTML pattern input, Chrome throws the following error at me:

> index.html:1 Pattern attribute value
>   `(((\(?)((\+|00)31|0)(\)?))([1-9])((\d{8}|\s\d{2}(\s\d{3}){2})|\-\d{8}))|((\+|00)(.*))` 
>   is not a valid regular expression:
>   Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
>   `/(((\(?)((\+|00)31|0)(\)?))([1-9])((\d{8}|\s\d{2}(\s\d{3}){2})|\-\d{8}))|((\+|00)(.*))/`: Invalid escape

I've tried removing a few escapes, but that throws a regex error at me. Does anyone know how to get this solved so it works in HTML?

The HTML I'm using can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fuk7hqvb/1/) and the regex [here](http://regexr.com/3fnn6).

Thanks.

```html
 <input type='text' id="phoneNumber2" name="phoneNumber2" class="inputField" 
 pattern="(((\(?)((\+|00)31|0)(\)?))([1-9])((\d{8}|\s\d{2}(\s\d{3}){2})|\-\d{8}))|((\+|00)(.*))" />
```

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: @ThomasAyoub The code can be found in the links I mentioned in the post. The HTML i'm using can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fuk7hqvb/1/) and the regex [here](http://regexr.com/3fnn6).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please next time post code HERE

Comment: Just remove the backslash before `-`.

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you. Will do!